# Debugging jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, events, handler

So, the other day I had a problem with one of the jQuery plugins. There's a textbox, I enter some characters, and it's either not working or working wrong. I've got the source, I've got the FireBug, and I don't know where to start. Something inside the code handles either the keypress event, or change, or both, and I'd like to put a breakpoint there.

The question is,

**How do I discover a handler for a particular event raised by a particular element**? I mean, not searching the code for "change", but dynamically? Can FireBug or any other tool help me with that, or maybe it could be done with a simple script?

Thanks

ulu

Comment: @do you mean like a callstacktrace??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), a Firebug plugging that shows up all jQuery objects in a much more useful way and highlights events on the objects that are on them.  It makes debugging jQuery work substantially easier.

Be sure to use non-packed JS code whilst debugging too.

Comment: FireQuery is really useful.  Excellent to be able to see data and event bindings on the DOM tree, having jQuery objects displayed in a really clear way in the console and watch panels.  Plus - it comes with a jquerify button that injects jQuery in to the page you're looking at!